# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in CFStreamOpen()

Tags: ios, ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller, exc-bad-access, http-live-streaming

This happens when I play m3u8's encoded and sitting on our server. 

The m3u8's are setup like so:

index.m3u8 > master list containing m3u8's for each bitrate

And then widthxheight-bitrate.m3u8 (like 1280x720-4500k.m3u8, just for example), specific to each resolution and bitrate, with these m3u8's now containing the names of the ts files. Standard HLS stuff.

I'm using a regular MPMoviePlayerController, and experienced the crashes multiple times, but not too frequently, like once in 40 mins or so of testing. 

The stack trace/screenshot from XCode is attached. I am on XCode 4.2, iOS 5.0 SDK, running in Simulator. I have not experienced the equivalent on a device, probably also because I have not tested/debugged for such prolonged periods when connected to the device.

This looks like a framework bug - but what I'd like to know is if anyone else has experienced this before. Google literally returned a grand total of ZERO results, as did a search for CFStreamOpen() on SO. And if you have experienced it, could you find a workaround, or better yet, the reason this happens?

I can't have a "simple at its core" video playback app crash in production on random unknown issues!

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: Have you tested your streams using the apple tools? Try it as described in this [tech note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2235/_index.html).

Comment: Yes, but the issue is that it happens almost randomly. All the videos I have play just fine most of the times - so it's not an issue with a specific file, or a specific encoding/m3u8 generation job on any of the files. Sometimes the issue happens as soon as I launch, and sometimes after almost 40 minutes of testing, on any random videos. I have had the opportunity to test/play through all the videos we currently have and it hasn't crashed at those times.